# Windows 11 creating new users profiles on every login

Tags: windows, windows-11, user-accounts

I've had a problem for about a week.

First off, I can't sign in like I usually do (via PIN code). The only way at the moment is to login with my Microsoft Account every time. I've tried setting up a PIN code again, but everything under "Ways to sign in" (or at least Facial, Fingerprint and PIN) is set to "This option is currently unavailable".

I can also see under "Windows Security" that I have a problem under "Account Protection". If I then try to click it to resolve it it just opens what looks to be "Microsoft Account" login screen, where it says "Just a moment..." and then just closes automatically again.

Today I also noticed, that since this problem occurred, Windows has created a new user under `C:\Users` every time I have logged in. So currently I have 20 new folders with names similar to `defaultuser100001.MYPCNAME`.

I have no idea what to do right now. So yeah, does anyone maybe have an idea or two about what to do?